# Spring Data JPA strange behavior

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to JPA and Hibernate and came across strange behavior. Consider the code below.

`License` entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class License {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private LicenseType type;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String activationKey;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<>();
    private long productId;
    private String productName;
    private long term;
    private long creationTimestamp;
    private boolean active;
}
```

`LicenceType` enum:

```
public enum LicenseType {
    NAMED
}
```

`Payment` entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Payment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private License license;
    private BigDecimal sum;
}
```

`LicenceRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface LicenseRepository extends CrudRepository<License, Long> {

}
```

`PaymentRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface PaymentRepository extends CrudRepository<Payment, Long> {

}
```

Bootstrap class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LsPocApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LsPocApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(LicenseRepository licenseRepository, PaymentRepository paymentRepository) {
        return (args) -> {

            License license = new License();
            license.setActivationKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            Payment payment = new Payment();
            payment.setSum(BigDecimal.valueOf(new Random().nextDouble()));
            payment.setLicense(license);

            paymentRepository.save(payment);

            // licenseRepository.delete(license); // This does nothing
            // licenseRepository.delete(license.getId()); // This deletes both licence and associated payment(s)
        };
    }
}
```

So the question is why the `licenseRepository.delete(license.getId())` works as intended, but `licenseRepository.delete(license)` does nothing? I assumed, they are logically equivalent. Or I'm wrong?

Please advise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the same happen if you change the License id from primitive long to Long class ?

Comment: @arocketman Yes

Comment: @alxg2112 Try to remove the Cascade from your relations mappings and check it.

Comment: @chŝdk Everything works fine without the cascades. Why this doesn't work with them, that is the question...

Comment: @alxg2112 It works when you delete Cascade, but why? Honestly I don"t know, I have been digging on the net for a while now and I haven't ever found an answer, check [this **thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688402/delete-not-working-with-jparepository) for reference.

Comment: @chŝdk Actually, If I remove cascades, I need to save licence and payment separately, same for the deleting. That's not what I want. The behavior I'm trying to achieve is when payment with license reference is added, license entry gets created in database table. And when I deleting licence, all corresponding payments are also getting deleted. Of course, I can achieve same behavior without cascades by rewriting the code a bit, but I desperately want to shed light on this mystery :)

Comment: Normally you should use Cascading to achieve this, but I don't know why it doesn't work with JPARepository `delete`.

Comment: It may be that the `equals(Object o)` method generated by Lombok is confusing things. For a JPA entity bean equals (and hashCode) should only use the `id` as that is literally the definition of equality for an `@Entity` bean

Comment: @Mark Added `@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id") @ToString(of = "id")` to the both `@Entity` classes, to luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your License implement Serializable? If so I think both calls will call the same method, the one intended for the id parameter. But since no License has another License as id nothing gets deleted.

The reason is that after type erasure all whats left of the nice generics are `Serializable` for the id and `Object` for the entity type. If the entity type also happens to implement `Serializable` that method is used since it is more specific. (I have to admit there is some handwaving going on in my brain, but the idea should be about right).

That is the reason why from Spring Data 2.0 (aka Kay) the method names of changed, so this confusion can no longer happen.

Comment: That's a really valuable remark, but `License` doesn't implement `Serializable` so I believe there is should not be any ambiguousness.

Comment: I've debugged my code and turned out you are absolutely right! Despite `License` doesn't implement `Serializable` for some reason, both `licenseRepository.delete(license)` and `licenseRepository.delete(license.getId())` calls invoke the same method `public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable` in `JdkDynamicAopProxy.java` class!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *Payment* entity saved to database using merge. So *License* did not added to session and and therefore *licenseRepository.delete(license)* doesen't work.

Try to change this lines in *Payment* class:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private License license;
```

to

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private License license;
```

Comment: Not true. Doesn't change anything afaik