# Why JpaRpository.delete(entity) don't actually delete the entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this entity

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "visits")
public class Visit {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private LocalDate date;

    @Column
    private LocalTime startTime;

    @Column
    private LocalTime endTime;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "services_booked",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "visit_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "service_id")}
    )
    private Set<Service> servicesBooked = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "visit")
    private Set<TimeSlot> timeSlots = new HashSet<>();

}
```

My controller performs delete action on service bean into transaction:

```
    @Transactional
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<DeleteVisitResponse> deleteVisit(@PathVariable("id") long visitId,
                                                           @RequestAttribute(USER_AUTH) UserAuthDto userAuthDto) {
// some logic    
            Optional<Visit> visit = visitService.findVisitById(visitId);
// check isPresent via Optional.map
            visitService.deleteVisit(visit.get());
// constructing the response
    }
```

And service bean just deletes it:

```
@Override
public void deleteVisit(@NonNull Visit visit) {
    visitRepository.delete(visit);
}
```

But actually it does not delete it. It performs sequential selects to resolve chained entities. Here are log records of that deletion: https://gist.github.com/bvn13/906582ad39720e033c24ddd6f59f906c

That's all. Why it cannot perform deleting operation?

Comment: What's that `visit.get()` in the controller?

Comment: " check isPresent via Optional.map" wait what?

Comment: what is your `visitService.findVisitById()` looks like ?

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688402/delete-not-working-with-jparepository

Comment: This might be similar/the same as https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1659?focusedCommentId=187922&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-187922 Could you try to make the id not private?