# Spring Boot JPA One To Many relation - deleting does not work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I am dealing with one issue. I have relation one-to-many and in my case it looks like that:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String title;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", cascade = ALL)
    List<TimePeriod> dates;
```

and TimePeriod entity looks following:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class TimePeriod {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Event event;
}
```

My JPA repo looks like that:

```
@Repository
public interface TimePeriodRepository extends JpaRepository<TimePeriod, Long>
{
}
```

When i execute following code:

```
event.getDates().stream().forEach(d -> {
            timePeriodRepository.deleteById(d.getId());
        });
```

I dont see that records were removed from database. They are still there. I understand that TimePeriod
is owning side in my case, so i understand it should work.

I am operating mainly od event entity, why i put there cascade.ALL option.

But when i had a cascade.ALL also on TimePeriod then not only related records were removed but also EVENT.

Another way which i tried i upadated event side like:

event.setDates(new ArrayList<>());

but after when i save event i was still able to see those date records in database.

Can someone let me know what im doing wrongly ?

Comment: So the instances of `TimePeriod` are not removed, right?

Comment: yes, it is still in database

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for a DataIntegrityViolationException when you delete the dates?

You should try to remove all dates from the event, save the event and then delete each TimePeriod instance:

```
List<TimePeriod> dates = event.getDates();
event.setDate(List.of());
eventRepository.merge(event);
dates.stream().forEach(d -> {
    timePeriodRepository.deleteById(d.getId());
});
```

Comment: I did not see any exceptions like data integrity. But when i did like u suggested it worked. Do i always need to update two sides? i thougth it can be done by one side, isnt it?

Comment: You need to when you don't want the cascading behaviour to take place.

Answer (score 0):

Does [Delete Not Working with JpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688402/delete-not-working-with-jparepository) answer your question? Your situation with bidirectional references looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

> But when i had a cascade.ALL also on TimePeriod then not only related records were removed but also EVENT.

The meaning of `CascadeType.ALL` is that the persistence will propagate  all operations (PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH) to the relating entities.

Instead I think you should try `orphanRemoval`.