# JPA in Spring: Unable to delete parent when last child has been deleted

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on some legacy code so unfortunately I'm unable to answer why the code has been designed as is. There are two entities: `Inbox` and `Upload`.

```java
public class Upload {

    // other properties...

    @ManyToOne(cascade = PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inbox_id", nullable = false)
    private Inbox inbox;
}

public class Inbox {

    // other properties...
}
```

`Inbox` does not have any relationship to `Upload`. Only `Upload` references the `Inbox` via the `inbox_id`.

Now I'd ilke to delete an `Upload` item like this:

```java
public void deleteUpload(long uploadId) {
  final Upload upload = uploadRepo.findById(uploadId).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
  uploadRepo.delete(upload);
}
```

This works fine. However, I'd also like to delete the corresponding `Inbox` but I have no idea how to do that. My current approach looks like this, but this does not delete in `Inbox` item.

```java
public void deleteUpload(long uploadId) {
  final Upload upload = uploadRepo.findById(uploadId).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
  uploadRepo.delete(upload);
  inboxRepo.deleteById(upload.getInbox().getId());
}
```

---

#### Update 1

I tried `@ManyToOne(cascade = {PERSIST, REMOVE})` but this leaves the `Inbox` remain in the database.

What puzzles me even more: Setting `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` doesn't show any `delete` statement for for the `Inbox` entity.

---

#### Update 2

In [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688402/delete-not-working-with-jparepository) I found that the following actually works:

```java
@Modifying
@Query("delete from Innox i where i.id = ?1")
void delete(long id);
```

Although I feel that this is not "the" way to do it.

Comment: @Jens I edited my answer. Already tried the `REMOVE` cascade but it has no effect.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint just before you delete the `upload` object? Is the `Inbox` reference present? Maybe it is not due to lazy loading?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA OneToMany not deleting child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011519/jpa-onetomany-not-deleting-child)

Comment: What happens when you call `inboxRepo.deleteById(upload.getInbox().getId())`?

Comment: @crizzis It depends on the cascade. Without `REMOVE` cascade, the `Inbox` item still exists in the database. When adding the `REMOVE` cascade: `org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class ...Inbox entity with id 170 exists!` So it seems as if the cascade attempts to delete it. But then removing the `deleteById` statement, the item isn't actually deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the Parent can remove it's child not the reverse.
In this context also `Inbox` is the owner where as Upload is dependent on `Inbox`.
If we take into account of Parent and Child then if there is no child parent can still exist but if there is no parent then child can not exist. Same rules applies in this context so you have to follow any of the alternatives that you identified.